# HTML Entity Comes as Entity Number in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web page, where i am dynamically inserting the entity `&#174` ® for the registered trademark, but unfortunately, it comes as `&#174;` in the page, what i am expecting is registered trademark.

I am using

```
$(selctor).text("&#174");
```

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe it should be `&#174` instead or just use `&reg;`.

Comment: sorry i used &#174; in my page . typo in question i corrected it.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/iwojoJe/1/edit?html,output). What's your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the solution is `$(selector).html('&#174').`.

The jQuery documentation provides an example of why this is so:

http://api.jquery.com/text/

`The code $( "div.demo-container" ).text( "<p>This is a test.</p>" ); will produce the following DOM output:`

```
<div class="demo-container">
&lt;p&gt;This is a test.&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

Comment: I am inserting that registered trademark via ajax from javascript. whether that may cause the issue?

Comment: Or, if it's encoded prior to being returned by the server, [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Comment: @MohamedHussain - If you are using a JavaScript function designed to insert plain text and feed it with HTML, sure, that's the problem.

Comment: @MohamedHussain I updated the answer with a very contrived example. Hopefully it'll help.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: as you said that is the problem. here i am inserting via the $(selector).text('&#174'), now i replace with $(selector).html('&#174'). Now it is working correctly. thanks a lot. put it in answer section.

Comment: @MohamedHussain - First, I think you should either edit the question or remove it. As it's now, it asks for a problem that does not really exist.

Comment: So basically this is a typo question. That's why you post code.

Comment: @remyabel Edited the question. Initially i thought it was html issue, the only i found that it was javascript issue. Thanks for the help.